# How to use variable in closure functions in php?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, gd, intervention

I am using intervention for php for image manipulations.
Is it possible to apply font size and color to text through a variable like this?
I have calculated $fontsize and $color above this but it says undefined variable

```
$img->text($string, $item['x'], $top, function($font) {
                        $font->file('assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf');
                        $font->size($fontsize);
                        $font->color($color);
                        $font->align('left');
                        $font->valign('top');
                    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use below syntax to pass variable:
Here you need to use a `use()` method.

```
$img->text($string, $item['x'], $top, function() use($font){
    $font->file('assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf');
    $font->size($fontsize);
    $font->color($color);
    $font->align('left');
    $font->valign('top');
});
```

**EDIT**

Here `$font` must be a `Class object` as this is used in the `callback` function. If you just want array then go for the following way:

```
$font = []; // initialize array
$img->text($string, $item['x'], $top, function() use($font){
        $font['file'] = 'assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf';
        $font['size'] = $fontsize;
        $font['color'] = $color;
        $font['align'] = 'left';
        $font['valign'] = 'top';
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I should define $font above this right?
Can you also please explain how should I define $font ?

Comment: Got it :D
 $img->text($string, $item['x'], $top, function($font)use($fontsize,$color) {

                        $font->file('assets/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf');
                        $font->size($fontsize);
                        $font->color($color);
                        $font->align('left');
                        $font->valign('top');
                    });
used like this ^
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It gave me error that font file must be included. The font file was already included. So the issue is I guess it doesn't expect an associative array in place of class object.